# How to work "script Table as" , "Create table" script in sql management studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to get the "CREATE" script for all tables.

Is there any script, like sp_helptext?

How can I get the script called when "Script Table as" -> "Create table" 
is selected?

Comment: You are interested in schema only. Not data. Right ?

Comment: Yes,firstly i want to get the schema. Getting data is another step.

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on the database and go to Tasks -> Generate Scripts.

This will walk you through scripting out all of the scripts you want.

Comment: you are right. Generate Scripts is doing well done this job.  But because of some authentication problem, i cannot use this solution.

Comment: Is the authentication problem one where you cannot access the table definitions? If so, then no tool will allow you to script the tables. Step one would seem to be to get the necessary access rights.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Generate script option in SQL Server.

```
Tasks->Generate Scripts
```

There you can take script as your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use what Stefan and gbn have suggested. Additionally if u want scripts for the exact replica for ur DB then look at [**Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en). It comes built into VS 2008 +

Comment: is there a new version? it isnot support sql 2008

Answer (score 0):

Already somebody give the right answer to this question

```
The best method is Rightclick the database then Tasks->Generate Scripts
```

But you are point out because of some reasons you cannot use the method.

if you are looking for a method using query then you can take the below method it will return the schema of your table

```
Go

Create Function ShowMyTableData
(
    @vsTableName varchar(50)
)

Returns
    VarChar(Max)
With ENCRYPTION

Begin

Declare @ScriptCommand varchar(Max)

Select @ScriptCommand =
    ' Create Table [' + SO.name + '] (' + o.list + ')' 
    +
    (
        Case
        When TC.Constraint_Name IS NULL 
            Then ''
        Else 'ALTER TABLE ' + SO.Name + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' +
            TC.Constraint_Name  + ' PRIMARY KEY ' + ' (' + LEFT(j.List, Len(j.List)-1) + ')'
        End
    )
From sysobjects As SO
    Cross Apply

    (
        Select 
            '  [' + column_name + '] ' + 
             data_type + 
             (
                Case data_type
                    When 'sql_variant' 
                        Then ''
                    When 'text' 
                        Then ''
                    When 'decimal' 
                        Then '(' + Cast( numeric_precision_radix As varchar ) + ', ' + Cast( numeric_scale As varchar ) + ') '
                    Else Coalesce( '(' + 
                                        Case 
                                            When character_maximum_length = -1 
                                                Then 'MAX'
                                            Else Cast( character_maximum_length As VarChar ) 
                                        End + ')' , ''
                                 ) 
                End 
            ) 
            + ' ' +
            (
                Case 
                    When Exists ( 
                                    Select id 
                                    From syscolumns
                                    Where 
                                        ( object_name(id) = SO.name )
                                        And 
                                        ( name = column_name )
                                        And 
                                        ( columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 )
                                ) 
                        Then 'IDENTITY(' + 
                                Cast( ident_seed(SO.name) As varchar ) + ',' + 
                                Cast( ident_incr(SO.name) As varchar ) + ')'

                    Else ''

                End
            ) + ' ' +

            (
                Case 
                    When IS_NULLABLE = 'No' 
                        Then 'NOT ' 
                    Else '' 
                End 
            ) + 'NULL ' + 
            (
                Case 
                    When information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL 
                        Then 'DEFAULT ' + information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT 
                    ELse '' 
                End 
            ) + ', ' 
        From information_schema.columns 
        Where 
            ( table_name = SO.name )
        Order by ordinal_position
        FOR XML PATH('')) o (list)

        Inner Join information_schema.table_constraints As TC On (
                                                                    ( TC.Table_name = SO.Name )
                                                                    AND 
                                                                    ( TC.Constraint_Type  = 'PRIMARY KEY' )
                                                                    And 
                                                                    ( TC.TABLE_NAME = @vsTableName )
                                                                 )
        Cross Apply
            (
                Select '[' + Column_Name + '], '
                From  information_schema.key_column_usage As kcu
                Where 
                    ( kcu.Constraint_Name = TC.Constraint_Name )
                Order By ORDINAL_POSITION
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ) As j (list)
Where
    ( xtype = 'U' )
    AND 
    ( Name NOT IN ('dtproperties') )

Return @ScriptCommand

End
```

you can call your function like

```
Select [dbo].ShowMyTableData ('tablename')
```

**Extension** :

if you need data too then you can use the following query

```
select 'insert into tablename values('+yourcolumnanme+','+columnanme2.....+')' from tablename
```